# first locating, then changing the value of a cell in a selected row in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, cell

Im trying figure out how I can change the value of a specific cell in a selected row of a datagridview. I am able to change the value but not in the highlighted row, only the first one. The hghlighting of the row is defined in the "find" button code.

For example: I enter a text, it search each row for that text in the specific column and then scrolls to and highlights/selects the entire row. (This Works Fine)

I then want to be able to get the value of a specific cell of the highlighted row by selecting the column name already present in the dropdownlist(combobox). It then gets the value of that cell and deducts from it a value present in a numericalUpDownCounter(nudQTY).

So far i can do this for different cells selected by column name (cbSupplList) but it only does it for the first row not the highlighted row defined by the "Find" button Code.

The following is my attempt so far:

```
 private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Code to search the alphanumneric Part Number (in Column1 header called "PART NUMBER") 
           and highlihgt the row*/
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            // Removes the row selection
            row.Selected = false;

            var cellValue = row.Cells["PART NUMBER"].Value;
            if (cellValue != null && cellValue.ToString() == tbPartNum.Text.ToUpper())
                {
                    // Scrolls the found row up and highlights the entire row
                    row.Selected = true;
                    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = row.Index;
                }
        }
    }

    private void btnSold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int cellVal;
        int newCellVal;

        cellVal = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[cbSuppList.Text.ToString()].Value);
        newCellVal = Convert.ToInt32(cellVal - nudQty.Value);
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[cbSuppList.Text.ToString()].Value = newCellVal;

    }
```

It seems it may have to do with the SELECTED ROW in the "Find" code and the CURRENT ROW in the "Sold" Code. Making the SELECTED.ROW = CURRENT.ROW would solve it.... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deselecting only Rows but no Cells.

**dataGridView1.CurrentRow** - "Gets the row containing current cell"

And Current Cell remains what it was = first cell of a first row.

In order to clear all selected rows/cells use

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection()
```

And instead of

```
row.Selected = true;
```

use

```
row.Cells["PART NUMBER"].Selected = true;
```

As currently you are selecting only row but not the cell.
I hope this helps...

Otherwise you might want to find relevant cell in **btnSold_Click()** the same way you did in **btnFind_Click()**

.

.

**EDIT**

complete solution for you

private void btnSold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    int cellVal;
    int newCellVal;

    cellVal = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[cbSuppList.Text.ToString()].Value);
    newCellVal = Convert.ToInt32(cellVal - nudQty.Value);
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[cbSuppList.Text.ToString()].Value = newCellVal;

}
```

I've just replaced **CurrentRow** with **SelectedRows[0]** and works fine.

Comment: thank you, im trying to make the selected row = the currenCell, how would i go about it. Ive tried dataGridView1.Currentcell = dataGridView1[cbSuppList.Text, tbPartNum.Text]... this does not work, it seems it wants an int for the column and row indexes instead of names(strings). Im sorry i am fairly new to this...

Comment: I've editted my solution. Please check what's below "EDIT" - should work for you.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.....the thing is i had tried this method before but did not include the [0]. Always learning from silly mistakes i guess. Once again thank you..